# How to use Approval Request link in reminder email?

Tags: workflow, approval-process, process

I am trying to send reminder emails to users if they have an approval process pending for a few days. I want the reminder email to contain the approval request link (merge field {!ApprovalRequest.External_URL}).

The issue I am having is I cannot access the Approval Request link in an email triggered by a workflow rule.

The initial approval email is triggered by the approval process itself, which populates {!ApprovalRequest.External_URL} fine as expected. But it seems a workflow rule does not have access to the URL as the merge field comes up blank in the email that is triggered.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can get the approval URL in a subsequent email?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're attempting to use the merge fields in an email template/email alert outside of the approval process, I don't believe it is expected to populate as noted below.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=approvals_considerations_mergefields.htm&type=0

You might be better off considering a report on Approval History (filter those submitted and not completed) and then a subscription to send to users if the record amount is greater than 0. If there's a lot of users/maintenance in that situation then, I'd assume apex would be the next bet (especially if the email is just a reminder with a link). Something as simple as a scheduled apex job running every day to find approvals that haven't been approved for x amount of days and then sending email to those users.
[image]